# Correct title for the maintenance announcement

Tags: terminology

I've been having doubts about this one announcement title that has been used in my company's software for a while now. I'm not an English native, so I can't be sure if my doubts are justified or if I just overthink things. I would appreciate your opinions.

So, here is a bit of context:
Once you open the SW there is a dialog window where general updates and info are usually posted for the users. But when we have the server maintenance, in big letters it displays the following title: (Announcement: *SW name* server maintenance in process.) and below in small letters are some details.

My issue is with this title sentence.

> (Announcement: *SW name* server maintenance in process.)

It feels incorrect, and i am also just more used to seeing "in progress" not "in process". Should it be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In process" is grammatically correct, just less common of a phrase. It also implies that a set series of steps are being undertaken that will end in completion, so the case of server maintenance is a good use case. "In process" does not seem to be used in British English, however.

More info: https://grammarhow.com/in-process-vs-in-progress/